# How can I find the domain of $x$ for which the function $g(x)\geq0\;$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, inequalities

I have this function ($x>0$)
$$f (x)=\frac{\sqrt{g (x)}+4 x \left(x^2+1\right) \sin (\pi  x) \cos ((3+\pi ) x)}{x^4+2 x^2+1+\left(4 x^2+\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \cos (2 \pi  x)\right)}$$

```
f[x_] := (
  Sqrt[g[x]] + 4 x (1 + x^2) Cos[(3 + π) x] Sin[π x])/(
  1 + 2 x^2 + x^4 + (4 x^2 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 π x]));
```

where $g(x)=4 x^2+\left(x^2-1\right)^2 \cos (2 \pi  x)-\left(x^2+1\right)^2 \cos (2 (3+\pi ) x)\;$.

```
g[x_] := 4 x^2 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 π x] - (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[
     2 (3 + π) x];
```

I want to check the range of function $f(x)$ for those values of $x$ in which $g(x)\geq0\;$.

-How can I find the domain of $x$ for which $g(x)\geq0\;$?

Comment: Did you try to use FunctionDomain[f,x]?

Comment: @tabi_k Yes, but the result is weird!

Comment: To get a quick impression of the range of f under condition g>=0, define `f2[x_] = ConditionalExpression[f[x], g[x] >= 0] `  and plot `Plot[f2[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 1000, 
 MaxRecursion -> 15, GridLines -> Automatic] `

Answer (score 1):

Try ( Thanks @SjoerdSmit helpful comment )

```
cond=FunctionDomain[{f[x], g[x] >= 0 }, x, Reals] //FullSimplify
(*1 + 6 x^2 + x^4 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] != 0 && 
4 x^2 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] >= (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 (3 + \[Pi]) x]*)
```

This condition gives (Thanks @user64494 )

```
Reduce[N[1 + 6 x^2 + x^4 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] != 0 &&      4 x^2 +(-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] >= (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[        2 (3 + \[Pi]) x]] && x>= 0 && x <= 10, x, Reals]
(*0 <= x <= 0.386763 || 0.590121 <= x <= 1.02279 || 
1.02333 <= x <= 1.47324 || 1.60461 <= x <= 2.03514 || 
2.06742 <= x <= 2.43253 || 2.67214 <= x <= 3.049 || 
3.11778 <= x <= 3.42438 || 3.70494 <= x <= 4.06349 || ...<= x <= 10.*)
```

visualization:

```
Plot[1, {x, 0, 10}, 
RegionFunction ->Function[{x},1 + 6 x^2 + x^4 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] != 0 &&4 x^2 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] >= (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 (3 + \[Pi]) x]]]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `FullSimplify` to make the result a little more compact.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Thanks, I modified my answer.

Comment: Additionally, the command `Reduce[N[1 + 6 x^2 + x^4 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] != 0 && 
    4 x^2 + (-1 + x^2)^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] x] >= (1 + x^2)^2 Cos[
       2 (3 + \[Pi]) x]] && x >= 0 && x <= 10, x, Reals]` results in `0 <= x <= 0.386763 || 0.590121 <= x <= 1.02279 || 
 1.02333 <= x <= 1.47324 || 1.60461 <= x <= 2.03514 || 
 2.06742 <= x <= 2.43253 || 2.67214 <= x <= 3.049 || 
 3.11778 <= x <= 3.42438 || 3.70494 <= x <= 4.06349 || 
 4.168 <= x <= 4.42848 || 4.72776 <= x <= 5.07828 || 
... 
  9.40322 <= x <= 9.49744 || 9.81264 <= x <= 10.`.

Comment: @user64494 Tricky definition off "~NReduce" , I didn't know the use `Reduce[ N@expr,...]`

Comment: With TrigExpand you can get the exact values of the zero-crossings  `sol = Solve[0 <= x < 5 && TrigExpand[g[x]] == 0, x] ` in form of root expressions like  `{x -> Root[{Tan[(\[Pi] #1)/2] - #1^2 Tan[(\[Pi] #1)/2] + 
      Tan[1/2 (3 + \[Pi]) #1] + #1^2 Tan[1/2 (3 + \[Pi]) #1] + 
      Tan[(\[Pi] #1)/2]^2 Tan[
        1/2 (3 + \[Pi]) #1] + #1^2 Tan[(\[Pi] #1)/2]^2 Tan[
        1/2 (3 + \[Pi]) #1] + 
      Tan[(\[Pi] #1)/2] Tan[
        1/2 (3 + \[Pi]) #1]^2 - #1^2 Tan[(\[Pi] #1)/2] Tan[
        1/2 (3 + \[Pi]) #1]^2 &, 0.59012140371407271166281}]} ` .